# Optimising multi join query on large table

Tags: sql, performance

Im writing an add on for an existing application and need to get the quantity sums for various transaction types. Each transaction type has a unique set of criteria ta_code, ta_type and ta_asc

The query below does return the necessary information, eventually, however the trans table has about 5 million records so it takes 4 minutes to run

```
SELECT t.qty AS tQty, sQty, rQty, mQty, lQty, aQty, xQty, t.itmcode
FROM trans AS t
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT sum(qty) as sQty, itmcode
        FROM trans
        WHERE 
            site = 127 
            AND ta_code = '12'
        GROUP BY itmcode
    )as tblS ON tblS.itmcode = t.itmcode
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT sum(qty) as rQty, itmcode
        FROM trans
        WHERE 
            site = 127 
            AND ta_code = '12' AND ta_type = '1'
        GROUP BY itmcode
    )as tblR ON tblR.itmcode = t.itmcode
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT sum(qty) as mQty, itmcode
        FROM trans
        WHERE 
            site = 127 
            AND ta_code = '15' AND ta_type = '4'
        GROUP BY itmcode
    )as tblM ON tblM.itmcode = t.itmcode
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT sum(qty) as lQty, itmcode
        FROM trans
        WHERE 
            site = 127 
            AND ta_asc = '147'
        GROUP BY itmcode
    )as tblL ON tblL.itmcode = t.itmcode
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT sum(qty) as aQty, itmcode
        FROM trans
        WHERE 
            site = 127 
            AND ta_asc = '155'
        GROUP BY itmcode
    )as tblA ON tblA.itmcode = t.itmcode
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT sum(qty) as xQty, itmcode
        FROM trans
        WHERE 
            site = 127 
            AND ta_asc = '155' AND ta_code = '15' AND ta_type = '4'
        GROUP BY itmcode
    )as tblX ON tblX.itmcode = t.itmcode                
INNER JOIN item AS i ON i.code = t.itmcode       
WHERE t.site = 127
GROUP BY itmcode
```

Each join seems to increase the ineffeciency but even run individually each joins select takes 10+secs to run. We only have read access to this database so cant alter it in any way.

I would be grateful if anyone could advise of a method or structure that can achieve this more effeciently.

Comment: depending on various factors you may get huge improvements copying the data in a separate table that you can optimize (indexes and so on). how often the data is updated? how often you run the query?

Comment: Move your LEFT JOIN in SELECT fields section. So your table will be  trans AS t JOIN item AS i

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think im going to use a combination of creating a new table to store historical totals received by the query rather than calculating each time and replacing the joins as suggested by Alex Buyny to get new info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be worth a try: remove all "left join" clauses, and compute conditional sums, something like that:

```
    SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ta_code = '12' and ta_type='1' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END), 0) as rQty,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ta_code = '15' and ta_type='4' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END), 0) as mQty

    FROM trans AS t

    WHERE t.Site = 127
    GROUP BY itmcode
```

Comment: Will probably mark this as the answer as the time it takes to get all the totals isn't much longer than each select takes to run. Nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the things I would try:

1. Adding Index on the itmCode column
2. Move the INNER JOIN item AS i ON i.code = t.itmcode as the first join
3. Use a temp table for "SELECT sum(qty) as sQty, itmcode FROM trans WHERE site = 127 AND ta_code = '12'
   GROUP BY itmcode" and then use it in the other left joins for the additiona ta_type as you repeat this query in every left join unnecessarily.

I also always would advise learning and using the MS SQL Profile if you are using MS SQL.

Comment: Thanks simply moving the join reduced execution time by about 40%

Comment: Great i would appreciate the +1